# Keyboard Intterupt with __aexit__

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

the __aenter__ and __aexit__ methods are meant to ensure cleanup,
But after a keyboard intterrupt is thrown, the __aexit__ method is not called anymore. 
I can imagine this being due to the fact that "with" statement is not part of the stacktrace of the current execution point(wild guess).
How to deal effectively with this problem in asyncio?

EDIT:
I created some sample code:

```
import asyncio

class manager:
    async def __aenter__(self):
        print("enter")


    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print("exit")

async def func1():
    print("func1")
    async with manager():
        await asyncio.sleep(1000)

async def func2():
    print("func2")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    raise KeyboardInterrupt

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(func1())
loop.create_task(func2())
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: What makes you think `__aexit__` isn't called? I ran a brief test with calls to print, and it shows that `__aexit__` does get called on python 3.5

Comment: I added a debug message in __aexit__ and it wasn't printed(python 3.7)

Comment: @JosephGrootKormelink you cannot catch keyboard interrupt with aexit, but, similarly to generators, GeneratorExit must be thrown when coroutine object is garbage collected. I believe it is asyncio bug. Filed it there: https://bugs.python.org/issue34074

Comment: How worried are you that you could have a misbehaving task that refuses to shutdown when given the opportunity? (eg. something with a bare except in a while loop). If you aren't worried then there is a fairly simple solution, otherwise there isn't really any answer.

Answer (score 3):

All your tasks are still there, you just need to decide what to do with them. If you have well behaved tasks then it should be as simple as cancelling them and then letting them run until completion.

eg.

```
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except BaseException:
    all_tasks = asyncio.Task.all_tasks(loop=loop)
    for task in all_tasks:
        task.cancel()
    loop.run_until_complete(
        asyncio.gather(
            *all_tasks,
            loop=loop,
            return_exceptions=True # means all tasks get a chance to finish
        )
    )
    raise
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Which produces:

```
func1
enter
func2
exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\python\asyncio_test.py", line 26, in <module>
    loop.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 295, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1254, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 125, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 301, in _wakeup
    self._step()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\python\asyncio_test.py", line 19, in func2
    raise KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt
```

If you have a badly behaved task then this implementation might fail to halt. One such implementation looks like:

```
async def bad():
    while True:
        try:
            print('bad loop')
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5, loop=loop)
        except BaseException as e:
            print(repr(e))
```